# Find in exits in php array

Tags: php, arrays

trying to find if value exits in the array. the problem here is that I get the array from websercive and I can get the result back in two formats

Format 1 is:

```
[SubCategory] => Array
        (
            [RefSubCategory] => normalPhoto
            [NameSubCategory] => normalPhoto
            [Description] => ד
            [Order] => 2
        )
```

Format 2 is

```
 [SubCategory] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [RefSubCategory] => Enlargement
                    [NameSubCategory] => Enlargement
                    [Description] => Enlargement
                    [Order] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [RefSubCategory] => normalPhoto
                    [NameSubCategory] => normalPhoto
                    [Description] => ד
                    [Order] => 2
                )

        )
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($SubCategory[0])){ //Format 2
    //search in each sub array for the value
    foreach($SubCategory as $key => $subarray){
        if(in_array($valtofind,$subarray)){
            echo "Value found in SubCategory[$key]";
        }
    }
} else { //otherwise it's Format 1 so just search for the value
    if(in_array($valtofind,$SubCategory)){
        echo "Value found in SubCategory";
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think this will create an error "undefined index 0"   for is_array($SubCategory[0])  for the first type of result.

Comment: No because if `$SubCategory[0]` is not an array then it's a string with the key `RefSubCategory`.  At least based on OP's example.

Comment: And on that case key 0 won't be existing.

Comment: You should first check for the existence of that.

Comment: My bad, thought in PHP even associative arrays were also accessible via numeric key.

Comment: In that case we can remove some redundant code, provided the formats always follow the rules in the example, answer updated.

Comment: Now I just need to spend the rest of the evening racking my brain trying to figure out why I was so certain you could use numeric keys on an associative array :P

Comment: It happens sometimes.. :)

Comment: Probably because `mysqli_fetch_array()` returns an array with both types of keys ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help. but I get error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)"